# Angular 6 - cannot read property of null, using a filter method

Tags: angular, filter, observable

pretty new to angular so this might be an easy question!

I have an `observable` that returns me a list of `objects`.

These `objects` have an optional `property`, and I'm trying to filter the list of `objects` based on that `property`.

```
getPersonWithHouse(houseID: string): Person[] {
  this.myService.getPersons().subscribe(persons => {
     this.personsWithHouse = persons.filter(person => {
         if (person.house) return person.house.id === houseID;
     });
   });
 return this.personsWithHouse;
}
```

so basically in this function I take a House as argument, then I subscribe to the list of all the persons, and I save in a variable all the persons that are in that house.

I keep getting `"cannot read property "ID" of null"`

and also a `"not all code paths return a value"`, but this is because I put an `If` without an `else`, but I don't know what `else` I could put there.

How can I fix this? the main issue is that if every `person` has a `house`, this would work, but as the `house` property is optional, some `persons` don't have one, so I get this error

thank you

Comment: "but I don't know what else I could put there" just put `return false;` after if statement.

Comment: "cannot read property "ID" of null" seems that problem somewhere else as in your code there is no "ID", I mean in upper case.

Comment: thank you for the input, I just wrote it wrong in upper case! the problem was solved with the solutions below and the return false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another condition

```
if (person.house && person.house.id) return person.house.id === houseID;
return false;
```

Comment: thank you, this seems to have solved the issue, didn't think of putting return false, I was always trying to return the object I get from the subscription

Comment: no problem. make sure to check as answer if this helped

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
persons.filter((person) => person.house && person.house.id && (person.house.id === houseID));
```